# Buttering bread using silicone cooking brush

Tags: butter, utensils

I have a bowl of melted butter and I'm trying butter some bread, but after repeated attempts I notice that no amount of substantial butter is being transferred on the bread.

Is the silicone brush inappropriate for the task, or am I simply just missing something?

Comment: I don’t know if there’s something specific like oils don’t stick well to silicone, but I find that the few fat “bristles” on silicone brushes works better for thick things like barbecue sauce than for less viscous liquids

Comment: It works pretty well if the butter is not melted fully to a liquid, it should be more of a thin mush that clumps to the bristles. You can add thin slices of cold butter to a fully-melted batch and mash it up until it forms the right consistency; about like warm sour cream.

Comment: that was a good point, fixed the problem by that, thanks! Dandavis

Comment: @dandavis that's an answer, you should post it as such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silicone brushes aren't inappropriate in general, but your specific brush may be.

We've bought several silicone brushes over the years, and found that some of them were almost useless for most liquids (and for butter).  Others worked reasonably well.  We found that the ones that had a maximum number of closely packed "bristles" worked the best, and I can use these with melted butter.

That being said, silicone brushes never work quite as well as traditional bristle brushes.